# How To Prevent Access To Unmounted Mount Point

Tags: backup, mount, rsnapshot

Ok, I have this in fstab

```
  //windows_mashine/Backup /backups cifs credentials=/root/.credentials,rw,_netdev,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000 0 0
```

I have rsnapshot in my cron which backups /etc/ and /usr/local/ and some other files to /backups

Recently I find that when other mashine is down and /backups cannot be mounted 
rsnapshot backups to physical folder /backups thus it eats partition / space. How can I avoid this?

Can I prevent any writing to /backups when it is not mounted (rsnapshot runs as root, since it need to backup some system files)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Another option is to set the directory to be immutable.  To do this you need to run the following command with the mount point unmounted.

`chattr +i /backups`

I do this on any directory that is intended to only be a mount point just to prevent this sort of thing.  Because there are situations where you're not in a position to add a check to see if something is mounted.  Like if the process isn't a script that you control or it's a human that is generating or moving the data.  This approach will prevent unwanted data getting written into an unmounted mount point in those situations.  I would still add the mount check to your scripts so that you can output meaningful errors though.

Comment: It works and doesn't require to modify anything except mount point folder. Great!

Answer (score 6):

Why not just have the backup script test whether /backups is mounted, and exit if not?

```
mount | grep -q /backups || exit 1
```

Comment: just modified my crontab as `if [ ! -z "$(ls /backups/)" ]; then /usr/bin/rsnapshot daily; fi;`

Comment: @jonny the best answer here.

Answer (score 2):

the easiest way to handle this is.. with rsnapshot directly.

You should have a look at the option `no_create_root`

HTH

Comment: that doesnt work since the mount point is there regardless of whether an external device is mounted there or not