# Prevent writing to unmounted sshfs mount point

Tags: linux, mount, sshfs

Assuming I have a folder `/mnt/mountpoint` that I use as a mountpoint for some `sshfs`-mounted directory:

```
sshfs user@host /mnt/mountpoint
```

Now, I want to prevent applications to write to `/mnt/mountpoint` while it is unmounted. Questions I found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/570255/prevent-the-possiblity-of-writing-data-to-an-unmounted-mount-point-directory) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/313994/how-to-prevent-access-to-unmounted-mount-point) have answers that imply using

```
sudo chattr +i /mnt/mountpoint
```

which works fine to prevent any write-access. Unfortunately, it also prevents me from mounting with `sshfs` as a normal user.

What would be the best solution for this? I would prefer a single sshfs-command or something that at least doesn't require root privileges. Should I forego the `chattr` approach and try something entirely different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mount point default permissions**

Create the mountpoint with

```
mkdir --mode=0500 -p /mnt/mountpoint
```

Only the creating user will be able to write to it.  You could pre-populate this from rc.local.  When you mount whatever filesystem lives on top of that mount point, it will pick up the permissions of that overlay that you had set when it was mounted.

On a side note, I would avoid `chattr +i` as that will confuse folks and cause troubleshooting fun down the road if not everyone is aware you did that.

Comment: That pointed me in the right direction! For completeness: `sshfs` needs the option `-o allow_other` so that the non-mounting user is able to interact with the mounted directory (which seems to be a `fuse` related thing)

Comment: This needs to be sudo, so the creating user is root.  Other users then won't have permission to mount since they don't have write access to the folder. This doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work with `chattr +i` by use of the `IdentityFile` option in `sshfs`.

For this to work you will need to generate and add your keys to the remote host.

```sh
ssh-keygen && ssh-copy-id username@host
```

After that's done you can use sudo with sshfs to mount the host.

```sh
# If not running the sshfs command from a script,
# you need to save the following values prior to running sshfs.
# If you don't, they will be interpreted as the root user's env variables.

sshfs_uid="$UID"
sshfs_gid="$GID"
sshfs_key"$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa"

# Please note that all options passed to sshfs are required.
# Using these options will allow your user to read + write to the mounted dir.
# If they are not passed, your user won't be able to access the mounted dir.

sudo sshfs -o uid=$sshfs_uid -o gid=$sshfs_gid -o IdentityFile=$sshfs_key -o allow_other username@host:/path /path/to/mountpoint
```

If you want to add this as part of a script or make it automatic on login, you probably don't want to enter the password each time.

To fix that:

`sudo visudo`

```sh
# Assuming your sudo group is "wheel".
# And assuming the permissions for your wheel group look something like this.
%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Add this line after the above line to allow sshfs mounting without a password
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/sshfs*
```

Comment: This works, but doesn't support password protected SSH keys.